# Using MYSQL Load Data with TXT file, need to ignore first line

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script setup to receive a CSV file.

I'm using the 'LOAD DATA INFILE.. REPLACE' function to read it into a table.

But I need to ignore the first line of the file, whats the most efficient way to do that?

The csv is < 100kb, around 350-400  lines

Comment: Are you using `fopen` and `fread`?

Comment: I'm using: `if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtfile']['tmp_name'])){
 $file = $_FILES['txtfile']['tmp_name'];
 $sql =  "LOAD DATA INFILE $file...`

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way for 'LOAD DATA INFILE' is to use 'IGNORE number LINES' clause.

[LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

e.g. `LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE table1 IGNORE 1 LINES;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function?